# How to include Laravel Echo in Angular 6 Project?

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-echo

I've been banging my head against the wall with this one.  I can't seem to figure out how to include Laravel Echo in my Angular 6 project so I can use it from within my components.

I run `npm install laravel-echo`, works no problem.

I noticed when I try to do:

```
import { Echo } from 'laravel-echo';
```

I get this:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'

I tried referencing the file in the node_modules folder:

```
import { Echo } from 'node_modules/laravel-echo/src/echo';
```

but got this:

> ERROR in node_modules/laravel-echo/src/connector/pusher-connector.ts(30,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Pusher'.

along with a list of many other missing dependencies. followed by:

> The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format

So, I tried adding it to my `angular.json` file:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/laravel-echo/dist/echo.js"
]
```

And it loads in the project, but I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
>      at echo.js:933

I noticed the file structure of the package looks like maybe it's made to be able to be imported like other modules:

[image]

Obviously I have no clue what I'm doing here.

**What is the correct way to add this package to my Angular6 project?**

Many Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but here's the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#receiving-broadcasts

Comment: I really am not sure about the compatibility of Laravel Echo with other frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, I've followed the documentation, but there isn't much there.  It shouldn't be a matter of compatibility, it's just a javascript package.  I suppose this is more of a question of how to utilize generic js packages with Angular 6.

Comment: i think `import *  as Echo from 'laravel-echo';` would solve this issue, check this out: https://github.com/chancezeus/angular-laravel-echo/blob/master/src/lib/src/services/lib.service.ts

Comment: @Hussein, thank you so much for the suggestion.  It's giving me the following error: `Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'Echo' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation`

Comment: I am adding this import to the `app.module.ts`

Comment: no you should add this to a service or a component, or even better just use the package in the link above

Comment: Oh wow, sorry, not sure how I missed that link, I'm going to give that a shot. Thanks!!!!